# DB constraints in face of quickly changing requirements in an agile environment

Tags: database-design

I am in a team where requirements are changing often.
I see keeping constraints in application layers makes our life easy.
If I am going to follow the best practice of specifying most constraints into DB, I see hard times for my team members. When a requirement change needs a DB constraint change, we have to migrate the whole data. And migration seems to be a big headache.
What should we do? What is the best practice keeping in view that requirement changes very often?

We want to keep DB schema flexible and yet have data consistency.

What constraints can we still impose on DB while keeping things flexible enough?

Comment: Why migrations have to be a big headache if the db handles consistency? Don't you have to migrate as well if it is handled by the applications?

Comment: Say, one of the fields of a table must not be empty. After some time we see a change in requirement that it can be empty. In application layer it is a matter of adding a if condition and removing it. We see this is easier than adding and removing such checks in DB.

Comment: OK, so this change might be simpler in the application 9although it's simple in the DB as well, just make a migration with `ALTER TABLE t ALTER COLUMN c NULL;` What about the reverse, when a column is nullable and then you want to enforce it as `NOT NULL`? In the application, you'll have to make the (simple) change the condition but you also have to check all the existing data as well and act accordingly (change NULLs to something or disallow the migartion). In the DB, it stays simple, just `ALTER TABLE t ALTER COLUMN c NOT NULL;` and run the migration (and check if it fails or not).

Comment: But the real issue I see is with complex changes. If you have everything in the database and all migration scripts in version control, it's easy to move the data from one version to another. Just execute the migrations. it's also very easy to examine the constraints as they are all in one place.

Comment: Do you mean, it will be worst if all constraints are only kept in application?

Comment: In that case, would it be easier to add all constraints into DB and whenever any requirement changes we should change the db constraints as well? and do migration...

Comment: In my experience it's impossible to enforce constraints properly in the application layer (foreign keys come to mind - I have yet to see the database without them that doesn't have invalid data after running for a while). Also data and the database tend to live longer then the applications. And  data that is of any value is typically accessed by more then just one application (e.g. export/import interfaces to other systems)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As a data professional, I'm going to tell you straight up to leave the constraints in the database.

However, there's no right or wrong answer, because it depends on what risk you're prepared to deal with.

If you don't want relational integrity, use XML or JSON or some other thing that isn't an RDBMS. But if you want to use SQL Server or Oracle or PostgreSQL, go right ahead and manage it in the app.

Somewhere along the line, though, there will be data corruption and orphaned records. That risk is real, but I can't tell you how big of a risk it is.

If the effort of fixing corruption like that is less than the effort of maintaining constraints in the database, that's a manageable risk.

On the other hand, if you can't bear the thought of fixing corruption or orphaned data, then leave the constraints in the database and spend some money on the right tools to help you with database changes and migration.

P.S. "Agile" is not an excuse for bad design or lack of documentation.

Comment: Amen for your "p.s."

Answer (score 7):

I get $50/hr to go in and fix databases. Almost inevitably, a big problem that is costing a lot of time and money is traced back to a shortcut that was made during the initial design phase. At the risk of nipping a future customer in the bud, here is my advice for free: don't do it.

The design of the database should built on two foundations. The first is, of course, the nature of the data itself. Analyzing the types, domains, relationships and so forth is a task that cannot be short-circuited. The second is data integrity. For Pete's sake, don't think of this as something that is a pain, an obstacle that must be avoided. If a constraint is needed, put it in. Without delay. You can thank me later.

So you have a bunch of app developers running around like chickens with their heads locked up in a drawer somewhere. What's else is new?

Don't let them anywhere near the database. Not even in the same room. Don't even think about letting them suggest schema design. Ask them two questions:

1. What data do you need access to?
2. What form do you need the data to be in?

Then develop what I call a "wall of abstraction." This consists of a bunch of views and supporting stored procedures. The views will give them database objects they can access -- if they really insist on gaining direct access to "the database." I wouldn't think twice about creating an average of ten views for each table. How do they want to see the data? Write a view for it.

The stored procedures are really what developers should be wanting. These can provide an extensive and flexible API so they can perform any operation on the data they want, when they want to do it, taking (or providing) the data in whatever form easiest for them to work with. No direct access to the database needed.

By flexible, I mean that this abstraction layer can be developed, redeveloped, altered and grown to your (and your developer's) hearts content -- without changing the structural layout of the database itself.

At one customer's site, I got there just as they were just finishing up a project that consisted of dropping a column from a table. The column turned out to be a duplicate of another column in the same table. But all the apps directly accessed the tables so there were any number of screens, forms and code all over the company (and it was a large company) that might use the column in a query or DML operation. I was surprised to learn that this particular project was started 12 months earlier. It took them a year just to drop a useless column from a table! When I suggested using views, someone said, "Yeah. But then we would have to maintain all those views," and the suggestion went nowhere.

A view is just a query. How difficult is it to maintain? But the drop column operation could have been accomplished in a two week sprint with no changes to app code!

Flexibility and data integrity -- you can have both. It just takes a little work and, yes, you have to maintain the views.

Comment: Start charging more.  Your customers won't mind.

Comment: I'm retired so the money isn't all that important -- but you may be on to something. Maybe I should charge more so they'll take my advice more seriously. ;-)

Comment: If you don't actually need the money, then you are completely in charge of your value.  Charge exactly what you feel you'd pay for someone with your skill-set.  If the customer doesn't like it, they are free to find someone else.  Or, I should say, *try* to find someone else.